# please explain me below javascript code

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

json object code from file upload.php which is shared to below javascript .
In below code i am saving all json object in an array .

```
                    $ret=array(); // declaring array 
                    foreach($imagick as $i=>$imagick)
                    {
                        $f=$fileName .($i+1) .".jpg";
                        $imagick->writeImage($target_dir . $f);
                        $id_object = _addMediaFile($name, $f, 0, $fileSize, $folder);

                        resize(400, 225, "$media_dir/$f", "$thumbnail_dir/$f", $type);
                        $id = $id_object['ID'];

                        _updateThumbnailFile($id,$f);


                        $data= array("ID" => $id, "name" => $name, "fileName" => $f, "fileSize" => $fileSize, "fileDate" => $fileDate, "fileType" => 0, "folder" => $folder);
                        array_push($ret,$data);            //sending it to array

                    } $imagick->clear();

                    echo json_encode($ret);
```

> below is javascript code. since i am passing json array. it doesnt
>   works. may be some changes in code with reference to array.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#addFileDropzone').dropzone({
            url: "modules/mediaFiles/uploadFile.php",

            maxFilesize: 2048,
            init: function(){
                this.on("success", function(file, details){
                    this.removeFile(file);
                   details = JSON.parse(details);

                    var type = "cat-image"
                    var img = "";
                    if(details['fileType'] == 0)
                    {
                        type = "cat-image";
                        img = "modules/mediaFiles/loadFile.php?id="+details['ID']+"&tn";
                    }
```

Comment: The part img="...." just defines a string.

Comment: Please be more specific about what exactly you don't understand. Or explain what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So presumably this is code for a file uploader. From what I can tell, after successfully uploading the file to the server, the server responds with a JSON object containing details about the file. One of the properties held within details is the ID of the image uploaded. This ID can be used to view the image from the server.

```
img = "modules/mediaFiles/loadFile.php?id="+details['ID']+"&tn";
```

This line in particular is storing the URL of the image that you have just uploaded to the server so that you can display it (Or anything else you would want to do with an image)

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful explanation . i have just updated my question with details about json object  details as well. actually i am uploading one pdf image with 3 page. converting them to 3 different jpg image.  how can i use them to retreive all three conveted jpg image from uploaded image to database. what changes do i need to do

Comment: Sure, I'll give a go at helping you out. Just a quick question about one of the properties you've got in your JSON. The fileType value, is that where you're checking what number page it is? So FileType can go up to 2? 0 being your first page, 1 being second, and 2 being the last page of the pdf?

Comment: no actually file type is different type of file to upload. 0 being for jpg  1 for pdf  and 2 for video. i am using imagick to convert pdf to jpg and store them in database. i need to retrieve details of all converted image .  then i am using those image file retrieved from database as thumnail image for downloaded file .

Comment: Ah ok. Well, from what I can tell, you'll need to rework your response slightly. It's difficult to say exactly what you need to do as I don't know exactly how you're storing the images you extract from the PDF. That being said, what you will need to do is store all of the images from the pdf, keeping track of each of their IDs, then provide each of the IDs within the details object. That way you'll be able to access the images from the frontend.

Comment: hey i dont understand properly about retrieving data from server using json object . can u suggest me what should i learn ....

Comment: You're actually already doing everything you need to be doing - You just need to put all of the images ids in your JSON object. So where you were using `"ID" => $id` You need to be doing something like `"ID" => [$imgOneID, $imgTwoID, $imgThreeID]` Where those variables are the ids of the images stored within the database

Comment: how do i put more than one image id in json object

Comment: Don't worry about that, that will be handled by `echo json_encode($ret)`. All you have to do is use the `[$var1, $var2, $var3]` The square brackets in php indicate an array, so by doing this, the ID field within the JSON will be an array of ids.

Comment: hi lewis  , can u please check the above code. i have made changes  . created $ret as array and store all infomation in that array  and passed through echo json_encode($ret).   now above javascript code doesnt save id of the image . which is url to  thumnail image.  most probably need to make some changes with reference to array declaration. need some help

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting but I'm on my phone. All you need to do now is change your javascript to save all three thumbnails. So change img to an array, and then add each URL to that array. You can access the id's via details[0]['ID'], details[1]['ID'], details[2]['ID']

Answer (score 1):

- `img` — [variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Variable)
- `=` — [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)
- `"modules/mediaFiles/loadFile.php?id="` — [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)
- `+` — [concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators)
- `details['ID']` — [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) on a [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) referenced by a variable
- `+` — concatenation operator
- `"&tn"` — string literal
- `;` — end of statement

> It just create a thumbnail image

No. It combines three things to make a string (which looks like it is possibly a URL) and assigns it to a variable.